# How to search a hierarchy in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say that I have two tables to design a hierarchy based access framework:

Table: org_hierarchy

```
org_id  org_name        parent_org_id
-------------------------------------
1       HQ              NULL
2       NorthAmerica    1
3       Europe          1
4       Asia            1
5       USA             2
6       Canada          2
7       UK              3
8       France          3
9       London          7
10      Paris           8
```

Table: `org_membership`

```
membership_id   username        org_id          
---------------------------------------
1               jim             1
2               john            9
3               jane            9
4               joe             10
4               jill            2
4               jake            8
```

Jim should have access to all areas as he has membership to the top most level (HQ), beneath which all other levels are nested.

John should only have access to level 9 (London) as there are no areas nested under it. etc

In SQL Server:

1. How would I get a list of all users who had access to London? (including those users who had membership by virtue of membership at a parent level)

   Expected results: jim, john, jane
2. How would I get all users who had access to either London or Paris? (including those users who had membership by virtue of membership at a parent level)

   Expected results: jim, john, jane, joe, jake